# Forbid users to change DateTime settings at their desktop WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, block, user-profile, permissions, date

What is the easiest way to block changing the Time and Date settings on desktop workstations running Windows XP?

Comment: Is it XP Pro or XP Home?

Comment: I think that is XP Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by disabling "Change System Time" policy for the defined group:

http://www.troublefixers.com/enable-disable-change-of-date-and-time-on-windows-xp/